# Getting all objects from Riak using erlang riak client

Tags: erlang, riak

Suppose I have "User" bucket.
I want to get all the users from it or at least 10.

As I understood riakc_pb_socket:get/3

The first argument is PID, the second is bucket, and the third - Key.

One way to get all objects is to get all the keys and then loop through them, but as I understand it's inefficient way.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the documentation on Riak Search and (possibly) Secondary Indexes:

https://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/developing/usage/search/

http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/developing/usage/secondary-indexes/

If you need to retrieve multiple users and can pre-calculate the "top 10" list, you can store the IDs of those 10 users as a separate object in Riak. Then, get that "top 10", object, and parallel-get the 10 user objects. This would certainly be faster, in general, than compared to either of the above methods.